# Video in beamer gets refreshed with \pause command

Tags: beamer, media9, multimedia, video

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[b]{Title}
% If the video is in the first frame, it often doesn't start (I use Adobe)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[b]{Title}

    % For Windows
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[xshift=-2.94cm,yshift=1.55cm,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
    \includemedia[
        addresource=./myvideo.mp4,
        activate=pageopen,transparent,
        flashvars={source=./myvideo.mp4
        &loop=true
        &autoPlay=true},
    width=5.7cm, height=3.20625cm, 
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}


    % For Linux
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[at=(current page.center),xshift=-2.94cm,yshift=1.55cm] {
        \movie[width=5.7cm, height=3.20625cm, poster, loop, autostart=true, showcontrols=true]{}{./video/myvideo.mp4}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \pause

    Text to be shown later.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I need to have a video in the slide, then after clicking some text needs to appear. If I use `\pause` `\onslide` `\uncover` the video gets refreshed (it flickers and starts over). The same happens if I use `\includemedia`.

I would like to avoid it, that is the video should keep playing smoothly after the text below appears. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

MWE for both Linux and Windows (you need to have any mp4 video in the same folder of the tex file).

Comment: `\pause` and its variants will always create extra slides and I do not think there is a way to sync media between slides. You could, however, slice the video into several clips and have several slides each playing one clip at a time.

Comment: Did you try `\uncover<2->{Text to be shown later.}` and no `\pause`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the suggestion. Not working, it still flickers and reloads. I edited the code such that now it is a fully MWE (you can use any mp4 file, the problem happens to all mp4 I have).

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks for the suggestion. That's unfortunate :( Even if I split the video, there will still be the "flickering" because the second half will be loaded, which looks ugly.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make that part of the slides a big video? Like, ... imagine that you screen-record a rehearsal and cut out the frames that flicker?

Comment: @Symbol1 I see, that could be a solution (or I could just add the text inside the video). In both cases though, I need to time my talk to synch it with the video.